# Factory pattern use for instantiating a complex object of a single class

Tags: java, oop, factory

I have an object which is created on the basis of few conditions, like this -

```
if (objType.equals("one-type")) {
        targetTableName = "one_type_table";
        sourceTableName = "one_type_parent";
        unitTime = 1;
        delayTime = 10;
    } else if (objType.equals("two-type")) {
        targetTableName = "two_type_table";
        sourceTableName = "two_type_parent";
        unitTime = 2;
        delayTime = 20;
    } 
Config databaseConfig = new Config(targetTableName, sourceTableName, unitTime, delayTime);
```

I have been told that my module has to be saved from this monstrosity and the pattern that can save me is Factory. So I decided to use that and create an interface like this -

```
public interface ConfigInterface {
public String getSourceTable();

public String getTargetTable();

public int getDelay();

public int getUnitTime();
}
```

and also created a concrete implementation of this interface called Config.

Then create a factory to build this object -

```
public class ConfigFactory {
     public ConfigInterface getConfig (String objType) {
        if (objType.equals("one-type")) {
        targetTableName = "one_type_table";
        sourceTableName = "one_type_parent";
        unitTime = 1;
        delayTime = 10;
    } else if (objType.equals("two-type")) {
        targetTableName = "two_type_table";
        sourceTableName = "two_type_parent";
        unitTime = 2;
        delayTime = 20;
    } 
    Config databaseConfig = new Config(targetTableName, sourceTableName, unitTime, delayTime);
    return databaseConfig;
  }
}
```

Now I just shifted my monster code inside another function. Even that is fine but my config interface is not really a superclass for many subclasses which are being generated by factory class. There is only one type of Config object, it has all those 5 fields and thats it.

I am sure I am either using it wrong or its not the right solution for this problem. Can anyone tell me whats wrong or is there another magical pattern to solve my problem and get me those ship its.

Comment: I think the crucial questions here are 1. who decides which `objType` will be used? That is, who calls the `getConfig` method? And 2. do you have to expect that the number of Configs will increase, and possibly even have to be extended by clients with their own configs? Possible solutions range from innovative concepts like "Config files" to built-in mechanisms like the http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ServiceLoader.html

Answer (score 2):

Why not encapsulate Config subclasses OneType and TwoType that set these values in their constructor. Then change the factory to the following:

```
public Config getConfig (String objType) {
    if (objType.equals("one-type")) {
        return new OneType ();
    } else if (objType.equals("two-type")) {
        return new TwoType ();
    }
```

Alternatively, I use this pattern with enums for this kind of situation:

```
enum ConfigType {
   one-type ("one_type_table", "one_type_parent", 1, 10),
   two-type ("two-type_table", "two_type_parent", 2, 20)
   ;

   ConfigType (String table, String parent, int unit, int delay) {
       ...
   }

   String getTable () {
      return this.table;
   }

   ....
}
```

Now you can generalize the factory code and work in terms of static enum types instead of runtime evaluated strings.

```
public Config getConfig (ConfigType type) {
    return new Config (type.getTable (),...
```

Comment: Won't that crate an explosion of classes ? If I can have 6 values of objType, that is same config class but with different values of variable, should I be creating 6 classes for each of them ?

Comment: If that is also a concern you should externalize these settings to a properties or yaml file. By giving each config a separate name they really are different classifications. Actually an enum might work well here I'll edit my answer.

Answer (score 1):

The size of the code in the question is small, so any implementation would be as efficient as the other.

If the `objType` comes from different class instances, say `TypeOne` and `TypeTwo`, then you could overload the `getConfig()` method, e.g.

```
public ConfigInterface getConfig(TypeOne type)
{
    // Create and return the "one-type" object
}

public ConfigInterface getConfig(TypeTwo type)
{
    // Create and return the "one-type" object
}
```

Otherwise, especially if there are many different types, consider creating an `enum` with all the possible values to `objType`, as opposed to using a string. You can then use a `switch` statement, which is more efficient than the consecutive string `equals` checks.

Comment: The String objType I get from user, and it does not come from a different class instance. Which would leave me with the factory implementation that I have in question. Which I think is fine, as it adheres to the rule, program to interface not to implementation. Although I cant see any big practical advantage of it.